# Sort foreach by function inside loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am making my first ever PHP app and I am flummoxed at the final hurdle.

I am looping my results and need to sort the results of a function inside a foreach loop in PHP.

If anyone has any insight into how I can do this it is much appreciated!

```
foreach($data as $d) {
echo $d["StudioName"]; // This will output "This is a test!"

echo distance($lat, $lng, $d['StudioLat'], $d['StudioLong']);}
```

Basically I need is to be sorted by the "distance" function results.

```
$sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM studios WHERE StudioLat BETWEEN $minlat AND $maxlat AND StudioLong BETWEEN $minlng AND $maxlng"; // Basic SQL SELECT Statment

$data = $dataBase->getQuery($sqlSelect); // This will run the SQL statment and return and associative array.
```

Comment: You can store `distance($lat, $lng, $d['StudioLat'], $d['StudioLong']);` in an array for each value and just sort that array

Comment: Are you building the `$data` array yourself prior to this? Or receiving it from somewhere?  If building, show that code.

Comment: I have edited the code to show the $data

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array using [usort and a callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) use ($lat, $lng) {
  $da = distance($lat, $lng, $a['StudioLat'], $a['StudioLong']);
  $db = distance($lat, $lng, $b['StudioLat'], $b['StudioLong']);
  return $da - $db;
});
```

After that, you can loop through the array and output its items, just like you did.